# How to match stream elements but return false if non exists?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream and would like to check if all match a filter. If all match, return `true`.

But, if the stream is empty, I'd like to return `false`.

How can I do this?

Example code:

```
public boolean validate(Stream<Whatever> stream) {
  // Problem: returns **true** if stream empty.
  // How can **false** be returned if stream is empty?
  return stream.allMatch(Whatever::someCheck);
}
```

Comment: or optional, have you read up on that?

Comment: You mean that when the given stream is empty you want to return false?

Comment: @user1803551 Yes, but if not empty, continue with the match.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use

```
public boolean validate(Stream<Whatever> stream) {
    return stream.map(Whatever::someCheck).reduce(Boolean::logicalAnd).orElse(false);
}
```

which expresses the intent. We map each element to a `boolean` value expressing whether it matches and reducing all of them with a logical *and* operation which will yield `true` iff all of them were `true`. `reduce` will return an empty `Optional` if there were no elements, which we map to `false` using `orElse(false)`, as intended.

The only disadvantage is that this is non short-circuiting, i.e. does not stop immediately at the first non-matching element.

A solution still supporting short-circuiting might be a bit more evolved:

```
public boolean validate(Stream<Whatever> stream) {
    boolean parallel = stream.isParallel();
    Spliterator<Whatever> sp = stream.spliterator();
    if(sp.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0) return false;
    Stream.Builder<Whatever> b = Stream.builder();
    if(!sp.tryAdvance(b)) return false;
    return Stream.concat(b.build(), StreamSupport.stream(sp, parallel))
        .allMatch(Whatever::someCheck);
}
```

This is a variant of [Eugene’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46076235/2711488), but it doesn’t loose characteristics or parallelism and might be a bit more efficient in general.

Comment: You can replace `Whatever::someCheck` with whatever compound validation. Chaining multiple `filter` calls is not different to combining the conditions via `&&`, e.g. in a lambda expression. And other solutions than creating a compound predicate are not possible with your initial approach either. After you’ve called `allMatch`, the stream has been consumed and no other validations are possible.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the `allMatch()`? I think it's more descriptive than `map().reduce(Boolean::logicalAnd)`.

Comment: Well, the second variant has the `allMatch` invocation. There is no other clean way, as `allMatch` simply is an opaque terminal operation that doesn’t support to get combined with another evaluation.

Comment: @Holger oh wow! that second approach is well so *you*. very nice! I had no idea a `Builder` is a `Consumer` and this makes implementation such a breeze here

Comment: [`spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#spliterator--) is officially a terminal operation though. I guess that means the implementation is not required to preserve lazyness.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee: the `validate` method is a terminal operation as a whole; when the method retruns, the stream can’t be used anymore. I’m not sure which implication to the laziness you have in mind.

Answer (score 3):

The following code will work (I tested it).

```
public static boolean validate(Stream<Whatever> stream) {
    return stream.reduce((whatever1, whatever2) -> Whatever.someCheck(whatever1) ? whatever2 : whatever1)
            .map(Whatever::someCheck).orElse(false);
}
```

How it works? We use `reduce` operation to check that every element matches the predicate, if it fails, we keep returning the failing one (in ternary operation). At the end, we map the reduced `Whatever` object to boolean, and if it's true: then all matched and this is not empty (`orElse(false)`).

Comment: …which is not different to my `.map(Whatever::someCheck).reduce(Boolean::logicalAnd).orElse(false)`, except that you might call `someCheck` multiple times on the same object, however, the total number of `someCheck` calls will be the same.

Comment: @Holger I've posted my answer few seconds before yours. But you're right, that's why I already upvoted your answer too.

Comment: Your variant is an interesting pointer to the possibility to query the first failed element too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK with losing your characteristics and parallelism, this for example:

```
 public static boolean validate(Stream<String> stream) {
    Iterator<String> it = stream.iterator();

    if (!it.hasNext()) {
        return false;
    }

    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it, 0), false)
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .allMatch(x -> x.contains("a"));

}
```

Comment: [`iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#iterator--) is officially a terminal operation though, although it might not be in practice.

Comment: @JornVernee yes, I was thinking in the direction of how many elements you want to examine from that Stream

Comment: You can solve the deficiencies of your solution by using a `Spliterator` instead of an `Iterator`. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46077388/2711488) contains such a solution. The remaining question is whether short-circuiting is worth loosing the clarity of the non-short-circuiting solution…

Answer (score 0):

Try `peek`

```
boolean[] flag = new boolean[1];
return stream.peek(t -> flag[0] = true).allMatch(Whatever::someCheck) && flag[0]
```

Comment: thanks, update to new `boolean[1]`. can you give a sample which scenario it might NOT work for sequential stream? and when/why are not guaranteed that it's not visible at && flag[0]? or did you mean `flag` will be copied to sub-threads in parallel streams?

Comment: I think this will be fine for sequential streams, even with the new optimizations allowed in Java 9. I'm not so sure about non-volatile access to shared state in case of parallel streams - might be worth a separate question.

Comment: Ok, since `boolean[]` is an Object, not primitive, no matter `flag[0]` will be set to true once, twice and more. when `allMatch` is returned, the value must be visible to main thread because main thread only comes after one of the sub-threads which have set value is done, the main thread and that sub-thread are not running concurrently. this is what i'm understanding.

Comment: The main thread will also participate in the stream evaluation, so it *will* run concurrently to sub threads, however, it is correct that there is a *happens-before* relationship between the actions performed by the sub-tasks and the result return from `allMatch`. This does not apply when short-circuiting, but since this can only return earlier when returning `false`, this is not a problem here. So this code works, but if someone tries to adapt it to reuse it for another use case, it might break.

Comment: @Holger thank you for the explaining. I thought main thread doesn't participate the stream evaluation and only return result when all sub-tasks are done(or broken). but i do have a question about: ''main thread will also participate in the stream evaluation", why or how? `       Stream.of(1, 2, 3).parallel().allMatch(i -> {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            return i % 2 == 0;
        });`
should i expect the result is returned in 1 second or 10 seconds?

Comment: @Hoger, by the way, can you please also let me know what's 'short-circuiting'? does it mean the result can be returned by main thread before all the sub-tasks are done? and which stream operations support that?

Comment: @123-xyz: the main thread will contribute, because otherwise, it’s an unused resource. Note, however, that the common pool has a default configuration to create “number of cores minus one” worker threads, so the total concurrency usually matches the number of cores. “short-circuiting” means that the operation might complete without processing all elements. It will still cancel pending sub-jobs and wait for their termination, but that’s not necessarily sufficient to establish a *happens-before* relationship of a a `peek` action of a sub-job whose result is not used and the main thread.

Comment: But as said, this is not a problem here. `allMatch` can only complete earlier if one element evaluates to `false`, so the `flag` is irrelevant, also the `peek` before evaluating to `false` will perform a visible write of `true` to the array and since all threads are only writing `true` to the array, there can’t be a contradicting write. If you want to know which operations may short-circuit, look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and search for “short-circuiting”…

Answer (score 0):

I already added two answers I now removed but the problem kept nagging on me so I gave it a third try and this time it works including keeping `allMatch`. Here is the code for method `validate`.

```
public static boolean validate(Stream<Whatever> stream) {
    final boolean[] streamNotEmpty = new boolean[1];
    return stream.filter(elem -> {
        streamNotEmpty[0] = true;
        return true;
    }).allMatch(Whatever::someCheck) && streamNotEmpty[0];
}
```

A shorter version would be

```
public static boolean validate(Stream<Whatever> stream) {
    final boolean[] streamNotEmpty = new boolean[1];
    return stream.allMatch(elem -> {
        streamNotEmpty[0] = true;
        return elem.someCheck();
    }) && streamNotEmpty[0];
}
```

The idea behind this is that we want to know if there was at least one element in the stream, so I created a `final boolean[]` where the value is changed within the filter-call. So at the end of the stream's processing we can check the stream for being empty or not and act accordingly when we return the result.

Here is a complete class including testcases to prove that - this time finally - I provided a valid solution.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StreamTest {

    public static boolean validate(Stream<Whatever> stream) {
        final boolean[] streamNotEmpty = new boolean[1];
        return stream.allMatch(elem -> {
            streamNotEmpty[0] = true;
            return elem.someCheck();
        }) && streamNotEmpty[0];
    }

    static class Whatever {
        private boolean checkResult;

        public Whatever() {
            this(false);
        }

        public Whatever(boolean b) {
            this.checkResult = b;
        }

        public boolean someCheck() {
            return checkResult;
        }
    }

    public final static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Whatever> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("empty list: " + validate(list.stream()));
        System.out.println("empty list parallel: " + validate(list.parallelStream()));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            list.add(new Whatever(true));
        }

        System.out.println("non empty true list: " + validate(list.stream()));
        System.out.println("non empty true list parallel: " + validate(list.parallelStream()));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1000) {
            list.add(new Whatever(false));
        }

        System.out.println("non empty false list: " + validate(list.stream()));
        System.out.println("non empty false list parallel: " + validate(list.parallelStream()));
    }
}
```

The output when executing it is:

`empty list: false
 empty list parallel: false
 non empty true list: true
 non empty true list parallel: true
 non empty false list: false
 non empty false list parallel: false`

Comment: That is basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083634/2513200), except for (ab-)using `filter()` or `allMatch()` for side effects, wich is arguably worse than just using `peek()` for this.

Answer (score -2):

```
return !stream.filter(Whatever::someCheck).collect(Collectors.toList()).isEmpty()
```

Comment: Maybe `.count()` is better since you don't have to create a new list just to see if its' empty

Comment: The problem with collecting into a collection is that it might cause an OOME (OutOfMemoryError) if the stream has many elements.

Comment: But the OP wants to know if all the elements match. Your code checks if any element matches.

Comment: @Eran I just realized that and deleted that portion of the answer.

Comment: This is just an inefficient way to express `.filter(Whatever::someCheck).count() > 0`, which is already an inefficient way of expressing `.anyMatch(Whatever::someCheck)`, which is not what the OP wants…