# Return list of single element if stream filter condition doesn't return any results

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm currently filtering a stream but if the filter doesn't return any matches I'd like to return a single default value. This is within a chain of additional streams so I'm using this to avoid the chain stopping if one step doesn't have any results.

Currently I'm fudging it by collecting the result of the filter into a list, if the list is empty, create my new default list and return it as a stream. If the list isn't empty, convert the result back into a stream to pass it back.

What is a more stream orented way to achive this without needing to go to lists and back to streams?

Comment: good question and description, but please post the code to better illustrate your description.

Comment: Look at ‘Optional’ class

Comment: It depends on how you intend to consume that Stream. For example, if you are only going to process the first element of the Stream (i.e. call findFirst()), you can concatenate your original Stream to a Stream holding the default value. Then make sure that your default value passes the filter.

Comment: I think this is an issue for steam creation, not reduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want a method similar to [DefaultIfEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_DefaultIfEmpty__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_) in C#. unfortunately, the Stream API doesn't have such method but luckily for you someone has already implemented something of this sort.

Taking the `defaultIfEmpty` method from [@Stuart Marks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649062/how-to-check-if-a-java-8-stream-is-empty/26659413#26659413), the use case is pretty simple.

```
static <T> Stream<T> defaultIfEmpty(Stream<T> stream, Supplier<T> supplier) {
    Iterator<T> iterator = stream.iterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false);
    } else {
        return Stream.of(supplier.get());
    }
}
```

For example sakes, assume you have a list of integers:

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,3,5,7,9));
```

and you want a stream with a single value if there are no even numbers in the aforementioned list.

The use case would be:

```
Stream<Integer> result = defaultIfEmpty(integerList.stream()
                                 .filter(e -> e %2 == 0), () -> 99);
```

This will yield a `Stream<Integer>` with a single element being `99` as the `filter` operation returned an empty stream. you can then chain further operations on the stream returned from `defaultIfEmpty` i.e.

```
defaultIfEmpty(integerList.stream()
                       .filter(e -> e %2 == 0), () -> 99)
.map(x -> x*2)
...
...
```

or apply subsequent `defaultIfEmpty` methods upon:

```
 Stream<Integer> result = defaultIfEmpty(
                   defaultIfEmpty(integerList.stream()
              .filter(e -> e %2 == 0), 
      () -> 99).map(x -> x* 2)..., ()-> -1);
```

At this point, you'll probably realise readability is being lost and that will remain the case as you compose further operations upon.

Nevertheless, this is the best possible way as I can't think of any other way to accomplish this while sustaining good readability as you compose more and more methods on the stream.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to avoid the need to collect the whole stream, avoid loosing the original `Stream` characteristics and keep (most of) its optimizations is to implement a custom `Spliterator` that handles the default value in case the original stream's `Spliterator` is empty:

```
public static <E> Stream<E> defaultIfEmpty(Stream<E> source, Supplier<? extends E> other) {
    final boolean parallel = source.isParallel();
    final Spliterator<E> originalSpliterator = source.spliterator();

    // little optimization for streams of known size
    final long size = originalSpliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown();
    if (size == 0) {
        // source already reports that it is empty
        final Stream<E> defaultStream = Stream.of(other.get());
        if (parallel) {
            return defaultStream.parallel();
        } else {
            return defaultStream;
        }
    }

    final Spliterator<E> spliterator;
    if (size > 0) {
        // source already reports that it is non-empty
        spliterator = originalSpliterator;
    } else {
        // negative means unknown, so wrap the source
        spliterator = wrap(originalSpliterator, other);
    }
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, parallel);
}

private static <E> Spliterator<E> wrap(final Spliterator<E> spliterator, final Supplier<? extends E> other) {
    return new Spliterator<E>() {
        boolean useOther = true;
        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(final Consumer<? super E> action) {
            boolean couldAdvance = spliterator.tryAdvance(action);
            if (!couldAdvance && useOther) {
                useOther = false;
                action.accept(other.get());
                return true;
            }
            useOther = false;
            return couldAdvance;
        }

        @Override
        public Spliterator<E> trySplit() {
            if (!useOther) {
                // we know the original spliterator was not empty, we will thus never need the default
                return spliterator.trySplit();
            }
            Stream.Builder<E> builder = Stream.builder();
            if (spliterator.tryAdvance(builder)) {
                useOther = false;
                return builder.build().spliterator();
            } else {
                // spliterator is empty, but we will handle it in tryAdvance
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long estimateSize() {
            long estimate = spliterator.estimateSize();
            if (estimate == 0 && useOther) {
                estimate = 1;
            }
            return estimate;
        }

        @Override
        public int characteristics() {
            // we don't actually change any characteristic of the original spliterator
            return spliterator.characteristics();
        }
    };
}
```

Usage example:

```
System.out.println(defaultIfEmpty(Stream.empty(), () -> 42).collect(toList()));
System.out.println(defaultIfEmpty(Stream.of(1, 2, 3), () -> 42).collect(toList()));
System.out.println(defaultIfEmpty(Stream.iterate(1, i -> i+1).parallel().filter(i -> i%3 == 0).limit(10), () -> 42).collect(toList()));
System.out.println(defaultIfEmpty(Stream.iterate(1, i -> i+1).parallel().limit(3).filter(i -> i%4 == 0), () -> 42).collect(toList()));
```

Output:

```
[42]
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30]
[42]
```

Comment: If laziness is not required to that degree, probing with `tryAdvance` and a `Stream.Builder` makes the implementation much simpler than the wrapping `Spliterator` (similar to the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46077388/2711488)). Even in the wrapping spliterator, the `Stream.Builder` is a more efficient alternative to the `AtomicReference`.

Comment: @Holger Good idea for the `Stream.Builder` instead of `AtomicReference`, I will change that when I have the time. I also noticed afterwards that my answer is very similar to yours on [How to check if a Java 8 Stream is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26649062/525036). I wonder if it wouldn't make sense to merge the two questions in fact – Aominè's code also comes from Stuart Marks' answer on that question.